# Highcharts with dynamic data $http.post angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

```
$http.post(galileoServer + "actions.php", {
        "action": "get-attendance-graph",
        "user": window.localStorage.getItem("username")
    }).success(function(result){
        //console.log(result)
        busyIndicator("hide");
        $('#attendance-graph').highcharts({
            credits: 0,
            tooltip:{
                enabled: false
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: '',
                style: {
                    display: "none"
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May']
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'No. of days'
                },
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                labels: {   //to disable points displayed
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            legend: {
                reversed: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                        formatter: function() { //function to avoid displaying zero values
                            if (this.y != 0) {
                                return this.y;
                            } else {
                                return null;
                            }
                        }
                        /*style: {
                         textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                         }*/
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Absent',
                data: [result.absentData]
            }, {
                name: 'Present',
                data: [result.presentData]
            }]

        });



    }).error(function(result, status){
        alert(status + "\nCouldn't connect to Galileo server due to network problem")
    });
```

I am trying to load the data via ajax but the graph doesn't gets loaded the graph loaded is blank.
The coding snippet is provided.
I also tried with the getJSON part, but it also didn't worked.
Kindly let me know the solution, as I'm unable to get the graph since last two days.

The console output is `{"absentData":"0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0","presentData":"30,31,29,30,31,29,31,31,28,31,30,31"}`

Comment: A blank graph is a sign that your data is not properly formatted.  First, check your console for errors.  Second, update your question with the output of `console.log(result)`.  Until you do that we can't help you.

Comment: The console displays perfect results. I'll attach the output

Comment: @Mark
The console output is http://prntscr.com/59p18w

Comment: In the future, udpate your question with the ajax call in text, a link to  screenshot makes it harder on people wanting to help.

Comment: Noted @Mark. Is that fine now? Or should I add some more details?

Comment: Nope, that's good, I'm answering now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is not properly formed for Highcharts.  You want an array of numbers, what you are giving it is an array of one element a string:

```
data: ["0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0"] // an array of a single string...
```

It's better that you fix this in your PHP code.  You'll need to build a php array of ints (do not build a concatenated string) and then use `json_encode`.

If you can't fix it in the PHP, you could do something like:

```
data: $.parseJSON("["+result.absentData+"]")
```

but this is somewhat ugly.

Comment: It worked! Found a work around which includes your code snippet also.